# Why is my array field changed when changing a memberwise clone of the instance?

Tags: c#

```
A a = new A();
a.Inc2();

class A {
        public int[] i = {1,2,3};

    public int this[int index]{
        get { return i[index]; }
        set { i[index] = value; }
    }

    public static A Inc(A a) {
        a[0] = 666;
        return a;
    }

    public void Inc2() {
        A B  = A.Inc((A)this.MemberwiseClone());
        // WHY this[0] == 666????
    }
}
```

Why in "this[0]" I have 666?
How can I get encapsulation in .

Comment: Because you set it with `a[0] = 666;`?

Comment: What is your question? What do you expect to happen and why? This has nothing to do with "this indexing", setting `a.i[0]` will yield the same result.

Comment: Even if you created clone using `MemberwiseCloe()` this will give you a shallow copy and new instance of `A` and `this` instance will have the same `int[]`.

Comment: From [`Object.MemberwiseClone`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone(v=vs.110).aspx): _If a field is a reference type, the reference is copied but the referred object is not; therefore, the original object and its clone refer to the same object_. Long story short, it's the same array

Comment: Compare with a situation where `a[0] = 666;` is replaced by `a.i = new[] { 666, };`. The original code mutates the *same* array (each of your two different objects has its own `i` reference, but both references point to the same instance because the cloning was shallow). The alternative code modifies one of the two `i` references to point to another array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MemberwiseClone makes a **shallow** copy

Comment: And because arrays are reference types.